# HTML inertia scrolling on mac os breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, scroll

I have a following situation:

I have a scrollable `div` and while i scroll down I want to replace some of this `div`'s children with other elements but the the following two conditions are met:

- total number of children stays the same
- scrollable `div`'s scrollHeight, clientHeight and offsetHeight stays the same

The problem is that when the elements replacing happens the intertia scrolling on Mac OS suddenly stops.

I have written an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ah5T8/

The first (from the dop) scrollable `div`, get its children replaced every other 100ms. The second doesn't. Try to scroll both `div`s, Inertia scrolling in the first one won't behave correctly. Why is that? How can I overcome that?

**NOTE 1:**

I'm using angularJS and `ng-repeat` to replace the elements with the following code:

```
function getArray(n){
    var res = [];
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
        res.push({text: i});
    return res;
}

setInterval(function(){
    $scope.arr = getArray(50);
    $scope.$digest();
}, 100);
```

**NOTE 2:**

You **need to** have a Mac OS and Magic Mouse or other pointing device that supports inertia scrolling to see this.

**EDIT:**

Funny thing is that it actually works correctly in Internet Explorer 11 on Window 8 via Parallels virtual machine. But it **doesn't work** in latest Chrome nor Safari on Mac OS 1.9.2